# Get image from a php file to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I want to get image from a php file (for example: http://abc.xyz.com/api/showImage.php) for a specific user through the user id & set the image in the image view of my iOS app. How can i do so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use Asyn download method when displaying images from the web.
You could create your own category on UIImageView or use the popular ones out there 
[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

```
[imageView  setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image from the above URL in the form of NSData :

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://abc.xyz.com/api/showImage.php"]];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

Comment: Its not working bro. Not sure whether the issue is user id or not!

Comment: Can you tell me what your server is returning when we hit that URL ?

Comment: Server is returning binary data.

Comment: Can you check whether imageData is coming out to be NULL ? If yes, then your server's problem, else you can use SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

Store response into array and then into an object say profile Object.I am using `SDWebImage`.
if U are geting image url at `detailsObj.profileImage`.Then use like below to set to `imageview`..

```
 NSLog(@"response is:%@",userDetailsArray);


ProfileObject *detailsObj=[userDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

//in place of detailsObj.profileImage use url server link which is getting image.

```
if([detailsObj.profileImage isEqualToString:@""] || [detailsObj.profileImage isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || detailsObj.profileImage.length==0)

{

    self.profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];
}

else

{
```

//without using SDWebImage

```
[self.profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:detailsObj.profileImage]];
```

//if it is NSData getting from server

```
self.profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:detailsObj.profileImage]]];
```

//or using SDWebImage

```
 [self.profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:detailsObj.profileImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];

}
```